# Counting entries in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a datagrid that is filled with a dataset from an SQL query.
What i would like to do is count how many occurrences there are of a certain entry, for example in Column 3 i would like to count how many times a string is repeated in the datagrid. Is there any way of doing this, perhaps with Linq? I initially tried doing this through an SQL query:

```
SELECT Count(*) Occurences
From myTable
WHERE Column_name Like 'stringPattern'
```

But the problem is that the database is pretty big and i already have the returned data so hoping to not have to re-query the database?

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following work...

**Original**

```
SELECT Count(*) Occurences
From myTable
WHERE Column_name Like 'stringPattern'
```

**DataTable**

```
var count = (from row in myTable.AsEnumerable()
             where string.Equals(row["Column_name"].ToString(), "stringPattern")
             select row).Count();
```

Comment: I received this error:
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataTable'.  'Where' not found.

Comment: @Peter Now realizing you're using the .NET DataSet and DataTable types, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the table you wish to query from the dataset you can use LINQ.

```
var count = myTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["Column_name"] == "stringPattern").Count();
```

Comment: Forgive me as i'm still learning so, is it something like this: 

        var count = dataset.Tables[0].Where(x => x["Column_name"] == "stringPattern").Count();

Comment: I received the following:

'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @jsmith i think you can do that only in .net 4.0

Comment: I think you may be right, I am pretty sure DataTable has an AsEnumerable() however.